# How to catch cannot connect to database exception

Tags: c#

```
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var a = reader.GetString(1);
                var b = reader.GetString(3);
                var c = reader.GetString(4);
                var d = reader.GetString(5);
                await context.PostAsync($" ### Please find below the fleet policy information \n #### Policy number - " +
                    $"`{a}` \n #### Policy type - `{b}` \n #### Property - `{c}` \n #### Number - `{d}` ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Fleet policy with number **{policyNum}** not found");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("cannot connect to database");

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        PromptDialog.Confirm(context, afterOkAsync, "You still want to check fleet policy?", "Didn't get that, Please select either yes or no", promptStyle: PromptStyle.PerLine);

    }
```

I want the code to catch the exception if database connection is not successful, but it doesn't work. Please what is wrong with the code? all others are working but i'm also interested in catching the cannot connect to database exception

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean? You have an uncaught exception? What is the type of this exception?

Comment: i just want to catch the cannot connect to database exception

Comment: Try it with a general `Exception` and look in the debugger the *exact  type* (not the message) of the exception being caught. Then add that specific catch-block for that specific type.

Answer (score 0):

If the database connection is not successful, It is possible that you get exception that different than SqlException. You just catch only when SqlException is thrown.

Below you can find the exception list for SqlConnection.Open :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx